# Doing an insert remapping for commenter

Tags: vim

I am trying to do a remapping when I'm in insert mode to insert a comment but am having a tough time figuring out what all the keys map to. What I am trying to do is:

:inoremap <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> ==> <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

Basically, if I'm in insert mode I want to get out of insert mode to insert the comment (leader+c+space) and then go back into insert mode.

What would the correct `:inoremap` mapping for this be? What I have right now is:

```
:inoremap <leader>c<space> <Esc><Leader>c<space>i
```

But this doesn't seem to work (at least the latter half of it -- it does seem to be executing the mapping command). Note: the plugin I'm trying to remap is:

https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter

> `[count]<leader>c<space> |NERDCommenterToggle|`
>
> Toggles the comment state of the selected line(s). If the topmost selected line is commented, all selected lines are uncommented and vice versa.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24630/18609).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From vim doc (`:help nore`):

> Disallow mapping of {rhs}, to avoid nested and recursive mappings

In other words, the `nore` part forbids mapping to be applied to the `rhs` (right hand side).

So in your case, the `<Esc><Leader>c<space>i` doesn't trigger the VimCommenter mapping for that reason.

To allow recursion, you can take off the `nore`:

```
:imap <leader>c<space> <Esc><Leader>c<space>i
```

Comment: Zordi -- thanks for this. Could you please explain why the `<Esc><Leader>c<space>i` part would be considered 'recursive' ?

Comment: To allow you to comment on hitting `<Leader>c<space>`, NerdCommenter created a mapping, which you should be able to see by using `:nmap <Leader>c<space>`. So by defining the mapping in your original post, you create a mapping which will itself call a mapping, that's what I called "recursion"

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that, instead of creating an insert-mode mapping for this purpose, just use the native [`Ctrl+O`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) mapping to run a single Normal mode command from Insert mode.

Assuming your leader key is set to the default `\`, you can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>

You'll be left in Insert mode at the end of this sequence.

The advantages of this approach over an insert mode mapping are:

- You don't need any extra configuration, since `Ctrl+O` is a native Vim command.
- This works for *any* Normal mode command, so you don't need to add extra mappings for other commands you might want to be able to access from Insert mode.
- Adding a multi-character mapping in Insert mode starting with `<Leader>` means Vim will always pause and hold if you insert the leader character. In this case, it will also pause when you insert `<Leader>` and `c`. I find that avoiding this kind of mappings of otherwise printable characters is usually best.